# Core data, model migration and universal framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I am using the universal framework from the link https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework. It am including the core data managed object model and other model classes inside the framework itself. But, I am having serious trouble to migrate the model. I have a single momd file like Model.xcdatamodeld and inside it are versioned model which are named like 1.xcdatamodel, 2.xcdatamodel, 3.xcdatamodel and so on.  I have also included the model in compile sources in the build phases inside the library.

I have also the options set for the model to infer the migration automatically. Although the model is inside the framework, it needs some reference inside the main application bundle and so I have created a link to point the file inside the framework. But, I could not get migration working. Is there some thing serious, I am missing or is it not possible to reference the modal inside the framework to migrate automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution to the problem. However it seems much like a hack. I am now referencing to the model using the modal version directly as,

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Modals.momd/3.mom"];
_managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
```

But, I am not very happy with this solution. Is there some better way to achieve this ?